# MVVM Navigation Switching ViewModels causes an error with animations

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I am trying to make a WPF application using the MVVM pattern.
I now want to be able to navigate between ViewModels, and for that I've used this article: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Basically, the Main Window Resources contain DataTemplates for each View Model linking it to it's view, and a Content Control bound to CurrentPageViewModel like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HomeViewModel}">
        <Views:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:VaultViewModel}">
        <Views:VaultView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:VaultsViewModel}">
        <Views:VaultsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
```

In the constructor of the Main Window I set CurrentPageViewModel to a new instance of my home screen view model and when I want to navigate, all I need to do is change CurrentPageViewModel and WPF will do the rest because of my use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I am sending Change Page requests to the main window from my View Models by <s>copying the code from MVVM Light's messenger</s> implementing the Mediator pattern, and this works fine, except when I have Storyboards playing.

I have two very nice buttons inside of my home page, which will grow a bit when you hover over them:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MaterialButton}" Width="400px" Height="400px" Margin="15px" 
    FontSize="24" FontFamily="Roboto" FontWeight="Bold" 
    Effect="{DynamicResource HomeButtonDropShadowEffect}" Command="{Binding DisplayVaultsView}" 
    Content="Vaults">

    <!--#region button effects -->
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" CenterX="200" CenterY="200" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>

    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>

                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                        To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="Stop"/>

                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                        To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </Button.Triggers>
     <!--#endregion-->    
</Button>
```

As you can see, the button's Command is set to DisplayVaultsView, which is a method inside of the HomeViewModel which sends the Change Page request to the Main Window.
Without these storyboards inside the button, this works just fine and the new page is displayed. However, with the storyboards, the following error is thrown once I click the button:
`System.InvalidOperationException: ''scaleTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.'`

This has led me to believe that the animation is still attempting to play, but since the Button is not in the current context anymore it can't find the property it's supposed to animate.

It's also important to note that the HomeViewModel is not thrown away when you navigate to another page, I've written my own Navigator class which keeps track of the ViewModels so you can navigate forwards/backwards without losing any changes (and without having to reload everything).

I'd like to know how I can solve this error, but it has also led me to the realization that I might need to "unload" ViewModels when switching to another one. I'm currently just keeping all ViewModel references inside of a List inside the Navigator class. So my other question is, should I "unload" the ViewModels when switching to another, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works, but I'm not sure as to *why* it worked.
I removed all of the XAML concerned with the animations, and moved the animating to the code-behind in `HomeView.xaml.`

Here's the code:

```
public partial class HomeView : UserControl
{

    private Storyboard _mouseEnterStoryboard;
    private Storyboard _mouseLeaveStoryboard;
    private DoubleAnimation _scaleX_In;
    private DoubleAnimation _scaleY_In;
    private DoubleAnimation _scaleX_Out;
    private DoubleAnimation _scaleY_Out;

    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _mouseEnterStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        ScaleTransform scaleVaultsButton = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);
        ScaleTransform scaleFilesButton = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);

        VaultsButton.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        VaultsButton.RenderTransform = scaleVaultsButton;

        FilesButton.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        FilesButton.RenderTransform = scaleFilesButton;

        _scaleX_In = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            From = 1.0,
            To = 1.08
        };

        _scaleY_In = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            From = 1.0,
            To = 1.08
        };

        _mouseEnterStoryboard.Children.Add(_scaleX_In);
        _mouseEnterStoryboard.Children.Add(_scaleY_In);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_scaleX_In, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_scaleY_In, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));

        _mouseLeaveStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        _scaleX_Out = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            From = 1.08,
            To = 1.0
        };

        _scaleY_Out = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            From = 1.08,
            To = 1.0
        };

        _mouseLeaveStoryboard.Children.Add(_scaleX_Out);
        _mouseLeaveStoryboard.Children.Add(_scaleY_Out);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_scaleX_Out, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_scaleY_Out, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));

        VaultsButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(Button_MouseEnter);
        VaultsButton.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(Button_MouseLeave);

        FilesButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(Button_MouseEnter);
        FilesButton.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(Button_MouseLeave);

    }

    public void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_scaleX_In, (Button)sender);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_scaleY_In, (Button)sender);
        _mouseEnterStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_scaleX_Out, (Button)sender);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_scaleY_Out, (Button)sender);
        _mouseLeaveStoryboard.Begin();
    }

}
```

I'm not sure as to why this does work and the XAML version doesn't, so I'd still like an answer to that question.